# Swift Get CLPlacemark from CLLocation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, geolocation, swift5

I have an array of custom `Item` type. This model has a location and destination property of type `CLLocation`

After I fetch this item I want to make two requests using `Geocoder` to fetch the `CLPlacemark` for the destination and location. However it is strange that I can either make a call for the location or for the destination. If I do both the requests, only the first one fires. The seconds doesn't fire. 
As you can see after the first call I'm not replacing the whole model in the array but just altering a property so I do not think that's the problem.

```
for (i, element) in self.categories[index].items.enumerated() {
    // either this 
    self.geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(element.location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in
        if let error = error {
            self.error = error.localizedDescription
        } else {
            self.categories[index].items[i].locationPlacemark = placemarks?.first
        }
    })

    // or this 
    self.geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(element.destination, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) in
        if let error = error {
            self.error = error.localizedDescription
        } else {
            self.categories[index].items[i].destinationPlacemark = placemarks?.first
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't submit parallel reverse geocoding requests -

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder/1423621-reversegeocodelocation)

> After initiating a reverse-geocoding request, do not attempt to initiate another reverse- or forward-geocoding request. Geocoding requests are rate-limited for each app, so making too many requests in a short period of time may cause some of the requests to fail. When the maximum rate is exceeded, the geocoder passes an error object with the value CLError.Code.network to your completion handler.

For a single `Item` you could save the problem by initiating the second geocoding request in the completion handler of the first, but this won't work for multiple items since you will submit several "first" requests in parallel.

You will need to adopt a more sophisticated approach, such as submitting operations to a serial operation queue.

Comment: I get it. Before I used to save the actual placemark as a dictionary to Firestore. But since a placemark could change during time, I would end up with outdated data. Do you think that could be a solution also or it's better to use a serial operation queue? What about the new Combine framework. Could i use it in this scenario ?

Comment: You could use Combine; You need some technique that allows you to ensure that only a single reverse geocoding request is active at a time.  Even then you may hit the rate limit if you have hundreds or thousands of locations